# Double permission entries in folder

Tags: powershell, acl

I am trying to change the folder permission using below code but after executing the `Inheritance From` is showing both `None` and the parent drive.

[image]

also Principal like `Everyone` and one user is missing the entries with `inherited from` `H:\`

Please let me know what is the issue in my code.

```
# Get the drive letter that you want to remove "Authenticated Users" from.
#$systemDrives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | where {($_.Name -ne "C") -and ($_.Name -ne "S")}
$systemDrives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | where {($_.Name -eq "H")}

foreach($driveLetter in $systemDrives)
{
# Define the folder path
#$folderPath = "H:\"
$path = $driveLetter.Root
# Define the username for the authenticated user
$username = "Authenticated Users"

icacls $path /remove:g 'Authenticated Users(M,W)'
# Grant the permissions
icacls $path /grant:r 'Authenticated Users:(RX)'
icacls $path /grant:r 'Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)(RX)'
icacls $path /grant:r 'Authenticated Users:(R)'
icacls $path /grant:r "Everyone:(R)"

# Get the existing access control list (ACL) for the folder
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path

#protect the rules and not preserve inheritance
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($false, $true)

# Apply the modified ACL to the folder and all its subdirectories
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Get-Acl | Set-Acl -AclObject $acl}

Write-Host "Inheritable permissions have been applied to all child objects in $path."

}
```